# Semaphores, Critical section, Mutex Examples in MFC & C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-c++, mfc

can any one tell me or give me a link saying about detailed description of Critical section, Mutex,semaphores with some sample example of how to use them in MFC & C#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might explain but documentation on MSDN is already pretty excellent. Consider visiting Following Links.

---

Here is the link to `Semaphores` in `C#` with Example

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx

`Mutex` and `Locks`

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

`CMutex` synchronization in `MFC`

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms386471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

`Critical Section` MFC

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

---

Hope these help

Answer (score 0):

Also consider "Visual C++ 6 Unleashed," full text availabe at [InformIT](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Visual_C_PlusPlus&seqNum=144)  (link to the multithreading section).  Even if you're on a newer version, most of the information in this book is applicable and valuable.

Comment: -1 I can't recommend a book that teaches how to use a compiler that has been end-of-lifed for over a decade, and was a pile of crap when it was current.  You can't find somethign that was written in the last *decade*?

Comment: Bull. It's readily and freely available and the classes in question have barely changed since it was written.